# How to resolve un-ordered JSON dictionary retrieved from YouTube Api?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I've been stuck on this for a while and cannot think logically how to resolve this, and would like some help.

Basically, I'm using the YouTube api to fetch all the video IDs from a changel. I store each of these IDs in an array, and I loop through its indices, each time calling this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

This allows me to get the video duration of each video, where I put it in another array of AnyObjects and convert it to a recognizable format.

Here's the output of my videoIDs array, as I fetch it in groups of 10:

```
videoIDs = ["173ZNVycdQo", "NztC0z1JNq0", "U2C81DNHw2M", "09XKD2sS60E", 
            "Wc0cVjv44Xc", "ENKHANzmeh4", "mIW5trLZJcM", "KW0ehzTVo-s", 
            "1MyVzWIwFs4", "HyTQBpZeJCc"]
```

The problem is in the for loop as shown here:

```
for (var j = 0; j < self.videoIDs.count; j++)
{
    self.getDurations("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status&id=\(self.videoIDs[j])&key=\(self.apiKey)")
}
```

And Here's my getDurations function:

```
func getDurations(urlString: String)
{
    let targetURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

    performGetRequest(targetURL, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in

        if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil
        {
            do
            {
                self.resultsVideoDurationsDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                print("resultsDict = \(self.resultsVideoDurationsDict)")

                let items = self.resultsVideoDurationsDict["items"] as AnyObject!

                // Loop through all items and add it to another dictionary
                for (var i = 0; i < items.count; i++)
                {
                    self.unformattedDurations.append(items[i])
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
            print("Error while loading channel details: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

At every iteration, the JSON of `self.resultsVideoDurationsDict` is different, i.e. the order of the video IDs within the `videoIDs` array does not correspond to the same order of data output from the JSON.

I know that due to time delays in the NSURLSession, some data may be fetched earlier than others.

Is there a way to remedy this to way to ensure my `self.unformattedDurations` contains the ordered data corresponding to the data in the `videoIDs` array?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Here's one possible output of `self.resultsVideoDurationsDict`:

```
resultsDict = [etag: "DsOZ7qVJA4mxdTxZeNzis6uE6ck/EfACrkkmn5_QpCjD89FgcTdjxVY", kind: youtube#videoListResponse, items: (
        {
        contentDetails =         {
            caption = false;
            definition = hd;
            dimension = 2d;
            duration = PT11M29S;
            licensedContent = 0;
        };
        etag = "\"DsOZ7qVJA4mxdTxZeNzis6uE6ck/7wjJ90GVQP7Bo9GwdX8LfdJ8jdg\"";
        id = HyTQBpZeJCc;
        kind = "youtube#video";
        snippet =         {
            categoryId = 22;
            channelId = UC5ltMmeC4YFaart1SSXdmAg;
            channelTitle = "Viet My Television";
            description = "";
            liveBroadcastContent = none;
            localized =             {
                description = "";
                title = "PSCD TIEC QUAN 4";
            };
            publishedAt = "2016-02-02T17:31:58.000Z";
            thumbnails =             {
                default =                 {
                    height = 90;
                    url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HyTQBpZeJCc/default.jpg";
                    width = 120;
                };
                high =                 {
                    height = 360;
                    url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HyTQBpZeJCc/hqdefault.jpg";
                    width = 480;
                };
                maxres =                 {
                    height = 720;
                    url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HyTQBpZeJCc/maxresdefault.jpg";
                    width = 1280;
                };
                medium =                 {
                    height = 180;
                    url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HyTQBpZeJCc/mqdefault.jpg";
                    width = 320;
                };
                standard =                 {
                    height = 480;
                    url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HyTQBpZeJCc/sddefault.jpg";
                    width = 640;
                };
            };
            title = "PSCD TIEC QUAN 4";
        };
        statistics =         {
            commentCount = 0;
            dislikeCount = 0;
            favoriteCount = 0;
            likeCount = 0;
            viewCount = 14;
        };
        status =         {
            embeddable = 1;
            license = youtube;
            privacyStatus = public;
            publicStatsViewable = 1;
            uploadStatus = processed;
        };
    }
), pageInfo: {
    resultsPerPage = 1;
    totalResults = 1;
}]
```

The id of that result is **HyTQBpZeJCc**, which corresponds to the 9th index of the `videoIDs` array, not the first index. The first output should be for video ID **173ZNVycdQo**. Therefore, different outputs are produced at runtime.

Comment: `print("resultsDict = \(self.resultsVideoDurationsDict)")` can you add this log to the comment

Comment: @sken3r.MI: I added output

Comment: because you are working with async request you will almost never receive the exact order,thus unordered list, i would create an dictionary with the key ID and set data, and when you will need it, for example iterating thru array check if the dictionary has the key if yes get data and do magic with it

Comment: You can create a model object, let say 'YTVideo' that contains videoID & items and used this as an array of 'YTVideo' rather than AnyObject. Then you can easily change or update any variables that was assigned inside the model.